sum of cpu cost present in every node in the actual query plan vs, STATISTICS TIME ON, both have big difference number
in general Why does the sum of CPU times from individual nodes in the query's execution plan  differ significantly from the total execution time reported by SET STATISTICS TIME ON? assume the query didn't use parallel excution.
why this case. whether this comparision is valid one?
example AdventureWorks 2022 DataBase.
i perform below query:
select name from sys.tables;

i got out from STATISTICS TIME
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 4 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.
Total execution time: 00:00:00.053

if i sum all the node cpu time from RunTimeInformation in sqlplan i got 9 ms. sqlplan link

It would help to show the query, execution plan, table definitions, etc ([mre] also helps)

@MatBailie For every query, I'm noticing a significant discrepancy between the CPU time reported by SET STATISTICS TIME ON and the sum of CPU times from individual nodes in the actual query plan, even after enabling SET STATISTICS XML ON. Shouldn't these values be more closely aligned, and if not, what might be causing this discrepancy?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Without seeing what you are seeing we can't help much. All I can say is that the CPU time on nodes represent the total for the whole subtree (everything underneath that node) so look at the top SELECT node in the plan.

If you don't provide the information requested, you're not going to get any answers. Please read [ask] with particular attention to Stackoverflow being geared to concrete examples, not generic questions.

Apologies for the lack of detailed information earlier. I have now provided additional details to clarify the situation. Please review the updated information, and I hope it provides a clearer understanding of the question.
